# Subclassing a subclass of NSObject in Swift (iOS) and setValue forKey

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, nsobject

I am writing a base model class which subclasses NSObject, and then each model will be a subclass of this model.

When creating a model I provide a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` of attributes to make up the model properties.

```
class Model: NSObject {

  var hi: String = "hi"

  init(attributes: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    super.init()
    for (index, attribute) in attributes {
      self.dynamicType.setValue(attribute, forKey: index)
    }
  }

}

class User: Model {

  var name: String = "Donatello"

}
```

When I do as below on the direct subclass of `NSObject`, it works:

```
let model = Model(attributes: ["hi": "bonjour!"])
print(model.hi) // prints "bonjour!"
```

and even doing the same on `User`, the subclass of a class inheriting from `NSObject` works:

```
let model = User(attributes: ["hi": "subclass bonjour!"])
print(model.hi) // prints "subclass bonjour!"
```

but if I try setting properties only available in this subclass, I get the classic `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.`

for example:

```
let model = User(attributes: ["name": "Raphael"])
```

causes error.

Why does this error occur when this object, as a subclass of a class inheriting from NSObject, should inherit from NSObject automatically.

Is this a problem with my fundamental understanding of subclassing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your understanding of something much more basic: classes and instances. Change:

```
  self.dynamicType.setValue(attribute, forKey: index)
```

to:

```
  self.setValue(attribute, forKey: index)
```

Comment: Works. Could have sworn I tried that, as I only looked up dynamicType afterwards... but clearly my understanding is flawed. Much appreciated

Comment: No worries. Very well-asked question, though next time try not to type non-compiling code into the question (copy and paste instead) - you omitted `attributes:` in the last test line. Keep in mind that most answerers will immediately copy your code out and paste it into Xcode, so you want it to be the right code. :)

Comment: I noticed you did that edit for me, and face palmed accordingly! I'll take your comments on board for next time, thanks.